# Sharepoint javascript in an input form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have created a custom list input form based on the default New.aspx template. I have tabs on my form, so I need some javascript to activate the selected tab. I have all of the code written, but I can't figure out where to put the `<script />`. If I put it in the header areas above or below the `<ZoneTemplate>` tags, I get various errors and the buttons on the ribbon stop working. If I put it in between the `<ZoneTemplate>` tags, the form loads, but not the javascript. Any help is appreciated.

J--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bascially, you want to put the code to set the active tab on the server side, not with javascript. Heres an example of a Sharepoint tabbed multiview:

```
<asp:Menu ID="menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem  Text="Tab 1" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem  Text="Tab 2" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>

<asp:MultiView ID="Multiview1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0"  >
    <asp:View ID="view1" runat="server">
        <div>STUFF</div>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="view2" runat="server">
        <div>STUFF</div>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

You then need to write a function server side to handle the tab clicks:

```
Private Sub menu1_MenuItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles menu1.MenuItemClick
    Try
        If Multiview1.ActiveViewIndex <> Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value) Then
            Select Case Multiview1.ActiveViewIndex
                Case PageView.Tab1
                    Multiview1.ActiveViewIndex = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value)
                Case PageView.Tab2
                    Multiview1.ActiveViewIndex = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value)
            End Select
        End If
        ActiveView(e.Item.Value)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

And a function to handle the Active View switching:

```
Public Sub ActiveView(ByVal value As Integer)
    Try
         Multiview1.ActiveViewIndex = value
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is all written in VB. so if you have any questions, I'd be happy to answer. I hope this gets you on the right track. For clarity, I haven't added anything related to page validation.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "You need to write a function server side...", where do I write that? How do I code behind a SP form?

Comment: This example is assuming that you are using SharePoint as the wrapper for your asp.net website. Basically, you write your webpages to work within SharePoint and use the dll your application spits out, along with the aspx files, to create your sharepoint site.